# Alias for multiple sequential commands?

Tags: unix, alias

How do I create an alias `c` that will `cd` and then immediately `ls`?

```
alias c='cd; ls'
```

Is there some kind of way to insert a special variable that represents the input? Or is that not the way that `alias` operates *at all*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct. Use a function instead.

```
c() { cd "$1" ; ls ; }
```

Comment: OMG - what keywords can I use to Google on more similar stuff like this?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/